# List of objects as Func<T, object> in dynamic query building

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, properties, func

I am hardly trying to create universal pagination mechanism with couple of extra things like dynamic parameters to search in. Below example works for me when I want to go over all `Func<T, object>` given from T object, for ex. `x => x.Name` or `x => x.Surname`.

```
public static List<Func<T, bool>> GetPropertyWhereClauses<T>(List<Func<T, object>> funcs, string queryPhrase)
{
    var whereClauses = new List<Func<T, bool>>();
    foreach (var func in funcs)
    {
        whereClauses.Add(o => func(o).ToString().Contains(queryPhrase));
    }
    return whereClauses;
}
```

My problem is when Func is a one to many relation, for example `x => x.AspNetRoles`. I would like to search in Name field of every AspNetRoles object at list. How can I loop through every element in `x => x.AspNetRoles`? I tried `property.GetType().IsGenericType` or `foreach (var prop in property.GetType().GetProperties)` but didn't work.

Comment: Give an example for the queryPhrase parameter.

Comment: example `funcs`: `funcs = new List<Func<User, object>>() { x => x.Name, x => x.Surname, x => x.AspNetRoles.Select(y => y.Name) }`, `queryPhrase = "LALALA"`. It searches well in `x.Name` and `x.Surname` props, but can't handle `x => x.AspNetRoles.Select(y => y.Name)`